# Coloration of an interval graph with constraints

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, computational-complexity, graph-colorings

Given an interval graph that represents a set of tasks, in a given period of time, to be assigned to a set of employees, the objective is to find a minimum coloring of this graph such that the total duration of the tasks corresponding to each color does not exceed a constant $W$ and there exists, for each color, at least to successive activities where the elapsed time between them is greater than or equal a constant $R$.

I don't know how to solve this problem or how to transform it to a know problem.